# Floating column breaks content from another column

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin

I've created some page based on 2-column layout (left column - `.nawigacja-lewa  &  right - .pdstr-prawa`). Content in right column breaks when left column has a lot of content - just look at huge gap between article and brown box "O Autorze".
It's somehow connected with the fact that left column has this CSS:

```
float: left; 
width: 225px;
```

and right column:

```
margin-left: 245px; 
float: none;
```

I know workaround for this problem, but I'd like to know what cause it. :)

[Here is the link.](http://kenticoems.azurewebsites.net/wojtek/bug/blog_post.html)

Comment: Please set up an example on, for example, JSFiddle.net with the least amount of code necessary. I don't want to go to your website and dig through the code.

Comment: I thought about JSFiddle but when I write "clean" code with only necessary CSS, there is no problem. So, the problem is somewhere deeper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is arising because some of your elements have been taken out of document flow (the floated elements) while others remain in document flow (the right column has been set to float: none; but has children elements that are floated).

Perhaps the easiest fix would be to remove the following code from the right column:

```
    float: none;
    margin-left: 245px;
```

And add the following code:

```
    float: right;
    width: calc(100% - 225px);
```

This floats the right column next to the sidebar, and defines the width as 100% of its parent's (blog-str) width, minus the width of the navigation column.

Comment: I was thinking about solution with "calc" or display these columns as table-cell in table div. Thanks for explanation with floating children.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing that issue cause you didn't set width for the right side section (content section). If you apply the below CSS, your problem will be solved.

```
.nawigacja-lewa{
    position:absolute;
    float:none;
}

.pdstr-prawa{
    float:right;
    margin-left:245px;
}
```